# Including JS files in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am currently working on a project using webpack. I'm sorry if this question seems silly, but it's my first webpack project and it's kinda hard to learn.
I want to add a bootstrap template to my project, but I have a hard time implementing it. I successfully managed to implement all css files needed for this template using:

```
import "../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
import "../vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css";
import "../css/sb-admin.css";
```

But I have a hard time to implement the Javascript files needed for the project. Including them in the HTML file like this:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="../vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>

<!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
<script src="../js/sb-admin.min.js"></script>
```

doesn't work.
Also requiring them in my app.js file like this:

```
// Bootstrap core JavaScript
require("../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js");
require("../vendor/popper/popper.min.js");
require("../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js");

// Plugin JavaScript
require("../vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js");
require("../vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js");
require("../vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js");
require("../vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js");

// Custom scripts for this template
require("../js/sb-admin.min.js");
```

doesn't work either. How can I include these JS files into my project?

Comment: what does your webpack config look like? I would say the proper way to do this in webpack is to declare a `vendor` [entrypoint](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) in webpack config so that you can actually take advantage of the code splitting

Answer (score 1):

It is *not the right way* to use bootstrap in **webpack**. There are many loaders in the webpack for using bootstrap. Try [bootstrap-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader). this loader will load the bootstrap styles and scripts which are needed (code-splitting). Since you are beginner in webpack I recommend you to check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cN0eUhoV_Gc) video on youtube for better understanding.